# Правильная настройка точки входа index.php в Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

**1.** Как правильно настроить index.php (точку входа /basic/web/) .

**2.** Зачем нужно подключать Yii.php?

**3.** web.php - как это настроить? И зачем именно этот файл нужен? Читал-читал, но так ничего и не понялm о какой конфигурации приложения идет речь.

**4.** И для чего это нужно?  создание и конфигурация приложения - какой конфигурации?  (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();

---

Я это сам писал, но забыл за два месяца. Да и не на 100% разобрался во всех нюансах, потому как приятельствовал с **yii2** не долго. Вот теперь, намерен крепко подружиться с ней, но для этого,  её нужно получше узнать.

---

```
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');


// регистрация загрузчика классов Composer
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
// подключение файла класса Yii
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
// загрузка конфигурации приложения
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
// создание и конфигурация приложения, а также вызов метода для обработки входящего запроса
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: web.php это конфигурационный фаил. Вы инклудите автолодер сформированный composer, потом вы web.php инклудите в переменную там array с настройками, и в конце концов вы запускаете приложение с этим конфигом.

Comment: @Naumov - А это зачем?  --> ' подключение файла класса Yii'              То есть я так понял этот index.php настраивать и не нужно, кроме дебага ?

Comment: можешь сдесь посмотреть http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов `index` не надо настраивать... `Yii ` это главный файл в ядре фреймворка, там тоже подключаются файлы для его работы.... но вообще это базовый файл, который никогда лучше не трогать,....кроме как убрать дебагер на продакшне

Comment: @Алексей Шимански Понятно, спасибо. Просто не очень приятно работать когда не знаешь для чего эта деталь, хоть и без знаний всех её нюансов все хорошо работает.